# Exponential r.v.s. problem

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function

Here is the question.

*A total of n people has been invited to a party for honouring a scholar.  The party begins at time 0.  The arrival times of n guests are independent exponential r.v.s. with mean 1, and the arrival time of scholar is uniform distributed between 0 and 1.
Find the probability that exactly k of the guests arrive before the scholar.*

For my understanding, 
Let X be people arrive party, $0 \le x \le n$
and Y be the arrival times of x guest

$pY \mid X=n\{Y=t\mid X=n\} = λe^{−λx}$ for $x\gt 0$, 
then given mean, $E[Y] = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 1$
i.e. $\lambda=1$.

So $pY \mid X=n\{Y=t\mid X=n\}$ becomes $e^{−x}$
as we have to consider the time before scholar, so $0 \lt t \lt 1$.
and $X=k$.

I know that I have to find $pX(X=k)$, which can be used the equation of $\frac{pYX}{pY}\mid X$.
but how can I find $pYX$?
or my concept is something wrong here?

Please help!!

Comment: what does something like "pYX" mean?

Comment: @sheron Welcome to Maths SE:)  __2__ things: I have reformatted your equations this time but the input interpretation may be wrong so in future use [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1) to learn how to format via $LaTeX$ and secondly, if someone gives an answer that is useful to you don't forget to tick it. all the best.

Comment: @BLAZE thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible approach:

- Suppose the scholar arrives at time $t$:

  - What is the probability a particular guest arrives before time $t$?
  - What is the probability a particular guest arrives after time $t$?
  - What is the probability exactly $k$ out of $n$ guests arrive before time $t$?
- What happens when you combine this with the scholar's arrival time being uniformly distributed?

  - Hint: $\displaystyle P(K=k) = E_T[P(K=k\mid T=t)]=\int_t P(K=k \mid T=t)\, p(t)\, dt$

Comment: Can you give more hints on find the probability for guest arrives before time t?  I am not familiar on the distribution, actually I haven't much idea on how to use them.....thanks

Comment: If $X$ is an [exponential random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with mean $1$ then the probability $X \le t$ for $t\ge 0$ is $1-e^{-t}$.

Comment: then X>t will be $e^-t$

Comment: Probability exactly k out of n guests arrive before time t, is it ${\binom{n}{k}\over n!}(1-e^-t)$?

Comment: I am not very sure am I do it  right....is that $P(K=k) = \int_0^1 (1-e^-t) (e^-t)$?

Comment: $P(K=k|T=t)$ is a binomial calculation.

Comment: so $p(t) = e^{-t}$ and $P(K=k|T\le{t})$$= \binom{n}{k}e^{-tk}\bullet(1-e^{-t})^{n-k}$?

Comment: Almost.  I think $P(K=k\mid T=t) = \binom{n}{k}(1-e^{-t})^k e^{-t(n-k)}$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Then how if I want to know the expected number of guests who arrive before the scholar?
It should be $E(K|T=t)$?

Comment: It should be $E[K]$ so you will need to integrate $E[K \mid T=t]$ over $t$